# Kernel memory leak when using a Linux system as router

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, drivers, memory-leaks

I am working on two embedded Linux systems (kernel-6.2.10) both based on Toradex colibri IMX6ULL SoM. The first one (system A) is configured to work as a wifi access point (with hostapd), and the second (system B) is connected to this access point (with wpa_supplicant).

When I want to make an FTP data transfer from the system B to my PC through system A, I observe a memory leak into system A. This only happen in this configuration. Transferring data from system A to my PC does not show any memory leak.

It seems to be reproducible with any kind of network communication but easier to reproduce with an FTP data transfer.

Using kmemleak, it seems that the memory leak comes from the Marvell driver mwifiex :

```
  unreferenced object 0x83a2f540 (size 184):
  comm "kworker/0:2", pid 43, jiffies 4294947832 (age 162.950s)
  hex dump (first 32 bytes):
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  backtrace:
    [<802864f0>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x188/0x2c4
    [<808946f0>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0xe8/0x194
    [<7f01af44>] ieee80211_amsdu_to_8023s+0x1b0/0x498 [cfg80211]
    [<7f1528e4>] mwifiex_11n_dispatch_pkt+0x7c/0x174 [mwifiex]
    [<7f1535ac>] mwifiex_11n_rx_reorder_pkt+0x388/0x3dc [mwifiex]
    [<7f1640f4>] mwifiex_process_uap_rx_packet+0xc0/0x200 [mwifiex]
    [<7f075ee8>] mwifiex_decode_rx_packet+0x1d4/0x224 [mwifiex_sdio]
    [<7f07858c>] mwifiex_process_int_status+0x850/0xd70 [mwifiex_sdio]
    [<7f1480a4>] mwifiex_main_process+0x124/0xa30 [mwifiex]
    [<8080b9c4>] process_sdio_pending_irqs+0xe4/0x1d8
    [<8080bc90>] sdio_irq_work+0x3c/0x64
    [<80134fa0>] process_one_work+0x1d8/0x3e4
    [<80135204>] worker_thread+0x58/0x54c
    [<8013c9f0>] kthread+0xcc/0xe8
    [<80100148>] ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c
unreferenced object 0x82fa2a40 (size 184):
  comm "kworker/0:2", pid 43, jiffies 4294947833 (age 162.940s)
  hex dump (first 32 bytes):
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  backtrace:
    [<80286228>] kmem_cache_alloc_node+0x198/0x2d8
    [<808922b8>] __alloc_skb+0x10c/0x168
    [<80894644>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x3c/0x194
    [<7f14ce9c>] mwifiex_alloc_dma_align_buf+0x14/0x40 [mwifiex]
    [<7f07852c>] mwifiex_process_int_status+0x7f0/0xd70 [mwifiex_sdio]
    [<7f1480a4>] mwifiex_main_process+0x124/0xa30 [mwifiex]
    [<8080b9c4>] process_sdio_pending_irqs+0xe4/0x1d8
    [<8080bc90>] sdio_irq_work+0x3c/0x64
    [<80134fa0>] process_one_work+0x1d8/0x3e4
    [<80135204>] worker_thread+0x58/0x54c
    [<8013c9f0>] kthread+0xcc/0xe8
    [<80100148>] ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c
```

Before going deeper into kernel driver code, which I am not expert in, I would like to be sure that it is the **only** solution to fix my issue.

Any kind of help would be appreciated !

Comment: Drop a bug report on the [kernel Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) along with all the info

Comment: @NicolasFormichella only if that's an upstream kernel driver. Otherwise they will be like "oh, nice a bug report for software that is not ours to take care of! You will have to tell NXP!".

Comment: `mwifiex` is a in-kernel driver @MarcusMüller